# how to test expecting timeout error in Chai

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm testing my tyscript code on nodejs and would like to test a function which is expected to be timeout error.

I've used should().rejected and something else but I have no idea how to test `timeout error`. Even in the [official document](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/), nothing about that.

How can I test that?

I've tried like should.rejected.

Comment: Are you using jest or mocha?

Comment: @marchaos chai!

Answer (score 0):

Use [fake timers](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/fake-timers/) from [sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/). With `clock.tick(ms)` you can simulate a time and then catch your timeout error